# add decile breaks to stat_function

Tags: r, ggplot2, distribution

I would like to add decile breaks to the following plot.

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(-0, 1)), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = dexp, n = 101, 
                args = list(rate=3)
  )
```

As an example of what I would like to achieve, here is another plot but I would like to **find a way to stick to** `stat_function` since I can easily change the underlying distribution and parameters and also the plot is always more smooth.

```
vals <-rexp(1001,rate=3)
dens <- density(vals)
plot(dens)
df <- data.frame(x=dens$x, y=dens$y)
probs <-seq(0,1,0.1)
quantiles <- quantile(vals, prob=probs)
df$quant <- factor(findInterval(df$x,quantiles))
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_line() + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=0, ymax=y, fill=quant)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=quantiles) + scale_fill_brewer(guide="none")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hacky, uses `pexp` with some rounding to calculate which decile each `x` location is in.  It doesn't use `stat_function` but has the same advantages as you mention.

```r
# Set up range and number of x points
x=seq(0,1,l=1e4)

# Create x and y positions with dexp
df <- data.frame(x=x, y=dexp(x,rate=3))

# Identify quantiles using pexp
df$quant <- scales::number(floor(10*pexp(df$x,rate=3))*10, suffix="%")

# Find x positions for breaks
xpos <- aggregate(df, x~quant, min)

# Plot
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=0, ymax=y, fill=quant)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=xpos$x, labels=xpos$quant)
```

[image]

Comment: This is nice but I don't understand why the last part of the graph is cut out. For example, If you change the rate to 1 you will get only 6 deciles. With `stat_function` it doesn't happen. If `stat_function` is not an option, could you please suggest a way to get the same graph with the added deciles? Thanks

Comment: I calculated the deciles of the entire distribution.  If you keep the x range to 0,1 then you'll only see about half the distribution because about half of it is above 1.  Can you be more precise about exactly which deciles you want and how you want to set the range?

Comment: I want to see all the deciles, from 0% to 100% over the full distribution with no cuts.

Comment: The full distribution goes to infinity, but you could change the first line to `x <- seq(0,qexp(0.98,rate=1),l=1e4)` if you want to get say 98% of it on the plot.